# How to view Traffic Sources for a specific page in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-4

Wow, Google Analytics 4 is frustratingly overcomplicated and nearly useless. Can ANYONE explain to me how to simply view the top traffic sources/medium of a specific page in GA4? I just want to view the traffic sources for one specific page. Is that possible?

Comment: It's just completely useless; is my conclusion after quite a lot of research.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Reports > Acquisition > Traffic acquisition. Press the "+" button next to "Session default channel group" to add a new dimension. Select "Page path and screen class" for your new dimension. Search the report with the URL of your page.